Testing for transfer overflow - rust error
I am trying to test for paranoid use case  of uint256 overflow on ether transfer to may contact:
    // deposit funds and mint tokens to  sender
function deposit() external payable {
    require(this.totalSupply() + msg.value > this.totalSupply(), "Max limit reached. No transfers until some tokens  are paid out");

So when total amount of funds  overflows,   I will get nice revert message (highly improblably but nevertheless)
In my hardhat  unit test  I  do:
            const [owner, customer] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

            const {chip} = await loadFixture(deployChipDeposit);


            await hre.network.provider.send("hardhat_setBalance", [
                await customer.getAddress(),
                "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF",
            ])
            //  create new block   so changes are on the network
            await mine();

            //  shall accept deposited amount
            await expect(chip.connect(customer).deposit({value: "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000000000"})).not.to.be.reverted

            await mine();
            
            //  shall be reverted dur to overflow
           await expect(chip.connect(owner).deposit({value: "0x1ffffffffffffff"})).to.be.revertedWith("Max limit reached. No transfers until some tokens  are paid out")

And expect that revert message.  However,   something deep inside  in rust code chrashes:

thread '' panicked at crates/edr_napi/src/result.rs:144:17:
internal error: entered unreachable code: Internal halts that can be only found inside Inspector: OverflowPayment
note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5
Aborted (core dumped)

Do I do something stupid?  Or can I rely  that actual  solidity  VM just reverts this transaction anyway because ether balance of the contract account is overflowing? Do Ineed this require at all?

I don't really see an overflow anywhere. You just use a custom require for checking some condition. You should test it with some small values to make life easier. A real uint256 overflow gives a panic probably, not a custom error.

I try to provoke  uint256 overflow on the  contract adress.   First I am sending  "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000000000" wei,    and then  "0x1ffffffffffffff" -  which  IMHO shall produce unit256 overflow when added.  I have require()  in my function.   but if it is fired it masked by internal crash in backend

I checkd it with smaller values,   and it works as intended.   I liked to cover  (highly improbable)  overflow  in  my unit tests,  and got a panic instead of rollback

I've never heard of anyone testing for value overflow. I guess it might be possible in some private blockchains, but I've never looked into those. If you plan to use public blockchains for your contract, I don't see any reason to test this

Being a new developer in this area  I am definsive.    And there is a mention of overflow checking in openzeppelin code: "Overflow check required: The rest of the code assumes that totalSupply never overflows" -   so I go ahead and write a test case

Added an answer to clarify some things.

'Do Ineed this require at all?" yep, someone can borrow tons of ETH / tokens/ whatever in a single transaction and overflow your expression. If there are bugs in you code , the atatcker actually may run away with funds.

'Do I do something stupid?" , the msg.value is 15 digits, but the zeros at the end of first depoist is 13 digits, you overflowed it, can't you see it?

Well,   It was my goal to produce overflow of uint256.   In this case is someone borrows that much ETH to overflow  balance of contact,  this someone just burns those funds and will be unable to withdraw them at all.  But Lauri explained this in accepted answer

I think you are mixing up different types of data.
Overflows caused by having too much Ether somewhere are basically impossible in any real network. You can simulate it locally, but it could never happen in any live network (even a live testnet) because it'd be impossible to get that much Ethers. So, anything relating to a transaction value or msg.value (the amount of Ethers sent along with the transaction) does not need an overflow check.
The situation is different for various arbitrary data inside smart contracts. A contract can have an integer that can overflow very easily. Those either need to be checked manually or left for the compiler to check automatically (available after Solidity version 0.8.x).
The OpenZeppelin code you're referring to (for example https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/2f0bc58946db746c0d17a2b9d9a8e13f5a8edd7f/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol#L64 ) refers to an arbitrary variable _totalSupply. It does not refer to Ether amounts.
As a new developer, it's very good to be cautious. But there's also a limit on what kind of tests are useful.
